# How do I make an horizontal navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav ul li a {
  clear float: right;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>1st Website</title>
  <head<body<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ess.css" media="screen">
    <div> <a href="#main">Skip to main content</a> </div>
    <h1>Jeremiah Njuguna Web Portfolio</h1>
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="Index1.html">Home</a> <a href="Education.html">Education</a> <a href="Family.html">Family</a> <a href="Hobbies.html">Hobbies</a> <a href="Likes.html">Likes</a> <a href="Dislikes.html">Dislikes</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

But it doesn't appear horizontal, instead it shows up vertical.

Comment: Do you have any html code?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>1st Website</title><head<body<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ess.css" media="screen"><div>
<a href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
</div>
<h1>Jeremiah Njuguna Web Portfolio</h1>
<div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="Index1.html">Home</a>
<a href="Education.html">Education</a>
<a href="Family.html">Family</a>
<a href="Hobbies.html">Hobbies</a>
<a href="Likes.html">Likes</a>
<a href="Dislikes.html">Dislikes</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Edit the question to include code. Read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your HTML is syntactly incorrect. Your closing <head> should read </head>

Answer (score 1):

li is a block element; so make it inline-block and give it a width, then it can float.

```css
nav ul {list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow: hidden;background-color: #333;}
nav ul li a {clear float: right;}
nav ul li  a {display: block;color: white;text-align: center;padding: 14px 16px;text-decoration: none;}
nav ul li {display: inline-block;width: 100px;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head><body>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="">elm1</a></li>
<li><a href="">elm1</a></li>


</ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the user agents apply `display: list-item` to `li` element. You must override it it in your css. To make it inline try display inline-block or inline, or try display block with float left.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `display:flex` :

```
nav ul {list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow: hidden;background-color: #333; display:flex}
nav ul li a {}
nav ul li a {display: block;color: white;text-align: center;padding: 14px 16px;text-decoration: none;}
```